# How can I pass None value in my test part?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

How can I get my first statement, when my value is N

Comment: What's with `stringg`, `keyy`, `valuee`? I don't understand why you'd use those names

Comment: I think during the parametrization those inputs becomes somewhat like this

`test_func(stringg='red=4,..', keyy='red', valuee=None, expected_result='green=7')`

Comment: It's because the output is ` green=7`, because there's an extra space in your input.

Comment: this works with no errors for me, I can't reproduce

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

I think during the parametrization those inputs becomes somewhat like this

`test_func(stringg='red=4,..', keyy='red', valuee=None, expected_result='green=7')`

same as

`test_func(stringg='red=4,..', keyy='red', valuee, expected_result='green=7')`

If you are not passing a value then, its default values are None.

When passing arguments, keyValue arguments should be last and default arguments must be first.

**Suggestion**: try to pass the inputs as key-value pairs. If you are not passing a value then its value is None.

Comment: I check two statements, and only this one give me failed) so maybe I can't do it @Samapath

Answer (score 0):

Ran the code in my editor and I see an assertion error. Your inputs are passed correctly but when you closely inspect the error you'll find that there is an extra space in the result string.

Assertion error looks like:

```
AssertionError: assert ' green=7' == 'green=7'
```

That is because your input `stringg` is split by `,` which causes the extra space to be part of the key `green`.

Pass `stringg` as `'red=4,green=7'` and it should work.

Comment: `E       AssertionError: assert None == 'green=7'
E         -None
E         +'green=7'` @Afaq, And I delete my spaces here too(in the stackoverflow).